# Builder for entities with cakephp3

Tags: cakephp-3.0, entities

I need some help with my entities in CakePhp 3.
The idea is to set some parameters to a new entitie during the init phase. Maybe with a builder ( function _setPrivateKey( ) ).

I really don't understand how can I do that.

When I write:

```
$this->Univer->newEntity();
```

I want to set automatically a property: for example i want to generate the `$cleAuthentification`directly and without writing `$univer->cleAuthentification = ramdomGenerate();`in my controller. But with a methode inside the entitie class. ( A builder I gess like in other languages ) But how can i do that ?

Here is my Entitie class:

```
use Cake\ORM\Entity;

/**
 * Univer Entity
 *
 * @property int $id
 * @property int $actif
 * @property string $cleAuthentification
 * @property string $clePrivee
 * @property string $clePublique
 * @property \Cake\I18n\Time $dateCreation
 * @property \Cake\I18n\Time $dateRelance
 * @property \Cake\I18n\Time $dateValidation
 * @property \Cake\I18n\Time $dateDernierAppel
 * @property string $domaine
 * @property string $nom
 * @property bool $refreshActif
 * @property string $traficMensuelCaptcha
 * @property string $traficMensuelSite
 * @property int $version
 * @property int $categorie_id
 * @property int $editeur_id
 * @property string $plugin
 * @property int $visiteurUniqueMensuel
 * @property int $saisieMensuelValide
 * @property int $clicMensuel
 * @property int $saisieUniqueMensuel
 * @property bool $getContent
 * @property bool $displayTab
 * @property bool $escape
 * @property bool $restrictionLDA
 * @property int $genre
 * @property string $age
 * @property float $cpeMin
 * @property string $dataComportementale
 *
 * @property \App\Model\Entity\TechnologyIntegration $technologyIntegration
 * @property \App\Model\Entity\Categorie $categorie
 * @property \App\Model\Entity\Editeur $editeur
 * @property \App\Model\Entity\Theme[] $theme
 */
class Univer extends Entity
{
    protected $_accessible = [
        '*' => true,
        'id' => false
    ];
}
`
```

Thx for the help !

Comment: You want to add extra properties to your entities before saving it into the db?

Comment: Please, post some code and be more clear

Comment: I edited the post

Answer (score 0):

A very easy and simple way would be to create a method in the entity like so:

```
public function initializeValues() {
    $this->foo = "bar";
    $this->cleAuthentification = this->randomGenerate();
}
```

and then do following:

```
$entity = $this->Univer->newEntity();
$entity->initializeValues();
```

Alternatively, if it would be enough to do this when you want to save the entity, you could place the code in your `beforeSave()` method in the Table class - see the docs here: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#beforesave :-)